# calling a .net library in xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android

I have created a .net assembly file from the MATLAB and used it in c# windows and c# web application and its working fine. Now I want to use this assembly file in xamarin but I am getting the error. 
C# code should work in xamarin too. isn't it??

In windows when i tried to fetch the r,g and b channels of image its working fine but when i am trying to do the same thing in xamarin it is giving an error.
windows code is as :

```
int i, j;
Bitmap image = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
int width = image.Width;
int height = image.Height;
Bitmap processed_image = new Bitmap(width, height);
try
{
    byte[,,] rgb = new byte[3, height, width];
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            rgb[0, i, j] = image.GetPixel(j, i).R;
            rgb[1, i, j] = image.GetPixel(j, i).G;
            rgb[2, i, j] = image.GetPixel(j, i).B;
        }
    }
    MWNumericArray narr = new MWNumericArray();
    narr = rgb;

    Salt obj = new Salt();
    MWArray u = obj.classification(narr);
    label1.Text = u.ToString();
   // MessageBox.Show(u.ToString());

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

}
```

and the xamarin code is as:

```
int i, j;
Bitmap image = bitmapimage;// bitmapimage the image (either taken from gallery or captured using camera)

int width = image.Width;
int height = image.Height;
byte[,,] rgb = new byte[3, height, width];

for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
{ 
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        rgb[0, i, j] = image.GetPixel(j, i).R;
        rgb[1, i, j] = image.GetPixel(j, i).G;
        rgb[2, i, j] = image.GetPixel(j, i).B;
    }
}

MWNumericArray narr = new MWNumericArray();
narr = rgb;

Salt obj = new Salt();
MWArray u = obj.classification(narr);
textview.SetText(u);
```

I am getting error in fetching the R, G and B channels.

'int' does not contain a definition for 'R' and no extension method 'R' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me to solve this error. Will be really great full. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you had taken the time to look at Xamarin's documentation, you'd have seen that `GetPixel` returns `int` and not `Color`. You have to create the `Color` instance using the int returned.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Well, to be honest, I was going to say this too, but actually, it supposed to return `Color`: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel/p/System.Int32/System.Int32/

Comment: @SoroushFalahati That'd be if the OP used `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which, according to the error message ("int does not ..."), he's not.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, He did use `(Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image` so if I had to guess, it would be `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. Please @Andrew, clarify the type of the `image`.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati You'd be guessing, because there's also [this one](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.GetPixel/p/System.Int32/System.Int32/)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thankyou for quick response. I have checked the documentation. The documentation says "Gets the color of the specified pixel in this Bitmap." but I don't need the color I need to get the pixel values of each color channel. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am new to .net and xamarin too.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati I am using the bitmap image and I am using the using System.Drawing;  This is what I understand. sorry if i didn't answered properly

Comment: Also, why are you calling `GetPixel` three times instead of storing the result in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are using `Android.Graphics.Bitmap`. The `GetPixel` method of this object returns an `int` that should be converted to `Android.Graphics.Color`. Change your code to this:

```
    var color = new Android.Graphics.Color(image.GetPixel(j, i));
    rgb[0, i, j] = color.R;
    rgb[1, i, j] = color.G;
    rgb[2, i, j] = color.B;
```

Also, as a side note, `GetPixel` is slow, very slow. I suggest working with the raw binary data using `Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer()` method. Read more here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer/p/Java.Nio.Buffer/

Comment: ok thankyou so much. Let me try this and I will get back to u.

Comment: Its not giving any error but it didn't solve the problem. Now I cannot load the dll file in xamarin :( Thanks for help. Stay Blessed